# Encrypt email messages when Amazon Simple Email Service Classic is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I checked the official documentation for [Amazon Simple Email Service Classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-an-email-using-smtp.html) but I can find an answer for my question which connection type I can use SSL encryption in order to encrypt the e-mail content:

- AWS SDKs
- API requests
- SMTP connection using JavaMail

The only solution for now is to use [API request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-ses-api-examples.html) but in this case I don't see option to send web e-mail.

Can you guide me how I can solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with SES, look at using the SES Java V2 API. You can find examples here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/ses/src/main/java/com/example/ses

(At this point, the SES guide does not have the latest Java examples in it. You need to look at the [Java V2 DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html))

Notice the  **SendMessage** example, which makes use of the [Java Mail APIs](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html). There are different libs you can use to encrypt email used with Java MAIL API. For information, see this content.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sending-email-java-ssltls-authentication/